# Connecting switch to a resistor in Simulink

Tags: power, batteries, matlab, simulink

This seems to be an easy problem but i cannot figure out how to do it. I have to use switch in my design so that when the voltage across two points excess a fixed amount the switch should be connected to port 1 otherwise port 3. To use that i use control port which is port 2 bu i cannot connect this switch to the rest of the circuit. You can see the design below. [image]

Comment: you are asking alot of very similar questions but are not accepting answers: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:144063+[matlab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are attempting to connect a SimPowerSystems domain node to a Simulink domain node...

The switch you are using is for simulink signals NOT electrical signals.

For simPowerSystems there is an IdealSwitch which takes a Simulink-domain control signal. This only open-circuits a signal signal & does not act as a double-throw switch. Linking two together & using a logic NOT on one would provide the same affect

--edit--

[image]

Comment: Sorry for that but i am beginner and trying to accomplish something. If i get the answers of my question i would not ask the similar questions as you can think. Thank you for your answer by the way. The problem about IdealSwitch is the gate signal. The gate signal is boolean but i need to control the voltage which is an analog value. How can i do that?

Comment: As I said, use two IdealSwitches and use a logic NOT.